# Ghidra unable to find the JDK

Tags: ghidra, windows-10

Unzipped the ghidra application. When I run the .bat file I get the following message

```
LaunchSupport expected 2 to 4 arguments but got 1
LaunchSupport expected 2 to 4 arguments but got 1
LaunchSupport expected 2 to 4 arguments but got 1

Failed to find a supported JDK. Please refer to the Ghidra Installation Guide's Troubleshooting section. Press any key to continue . . .
```

Even though the JDK is installed and I have set the path too in environment variables.
What could be the reason for this ?

Comment: What JDK versions (and from which provider/distributor) do you have installed? Check the output of `java -version`.

Comment: this needs more information. can you show us java version as @Robert suggested and also your path variables and also from where you downloaded ghidra?

Comment: Hi, I got it working. Some configuration issue only. I reinstalled JDK and JRE and included them in environment variables. Is there any alternative to putting things in the path of environment variables or it's always required. I think such a thing is not there for linux. Manually going and specifying some path etc...

Comment: Environment variables always need to be set, regardless of OS. https://ghidra-sre.org/InstallationGuide.html#JavaNotes